# Thymeleaf - th:ref convet & to &amp;

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf.
I've a link build with th:ref

```
<a th:href="@{http://www.pippo.com/a=3&y=4&u=10}">
```

That is converted into

```
http://www.pippo.com/a=3&amp;y=4&amp;u=10
```

So & is converted into &

How can i convert & to & ?

Thanks

Comment: It's correct to convert ampersands in urls like this: `/a=3&amp;y=4&amp;u=10`. If you click it does it not work? See this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/…

Answer (score 0):

`th:href` is meant to be used for relative urls or urls that come (partly) from a model variable.

This Means that in your case with a static url you should be using regular `href` making `<a href="http://www.pippo.com/a=3&y=4&u=10"></a>`

A secondary issue might be using `&` as part of the url, this character is normally reserved for url paramaters and might not behave like you expect it to if you use it as an url part.
Looking at your url I would expect it to look like `http://www.pippo.com?a=3&y=4&u=10` in thymeleaf this could be `@{http://www.pippo.com(a=3,y=4,u=10)}`